# Add a button or label to a combobox

Tags: delphi, vcl

How can I add a button with OnClick event, or a label, to the bottom of the drop-down list for a VCL `TComboBox`?  Even if it is empty.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: I want add a component button or label to a combobox at the end of it in the list section and add a onclick event to do samthing .sorry for my langue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native ComboBox controls do not support what you are asking for.

However, you can use the Win32 API [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775939.aspx) function to get the `HWND` of the drop-down list and then use the Win32 API to manipulate it directly, like adding child windows to it, subclassing it to intercept window messages, etc.